# Django ORG issues multiple SAVEPOINT commands to PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions

I have a Django database transaction (by using `@transaction.atomic`) that creates thousands of models and saves each of them. When I log the SQL sentences I see that each `INSERT INTO` statement is wrapped like so:

```
SAVEPOINT "..."; args=None
INSERT INTO ...
RELEASE SAVEPOINT "..."; args=None
```

I suspected my code has two `@atomic` decorators - one around the outer function and another around the function that creates each of the thousands of models, but no - I found only one reference to transaction.atomic in the entire code.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Even if your code only uses one `atomic` decorator, the underlying Django call may be using `atomic` as well.